# Moving wordpress site from one machine into another

Tags: theme-options, migration

How to transfer wordpress complete site from one machine into another?
i try many times but it missing rev slider , widgets , metapost need help pls

Comment: Have you read the Codex on [Moving WordPress](https://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress)?

Comment: yes i already read this

Comment: i actually try another site which does not include rev slider or metabox its work fine after migrate..

Answer (score 0):

The most common problem comes from changing the URL of your site.

WordPress (and plugins like Revolution Slider) stores some data as [serialized](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) strings. A portion of that would look like s:18:"http://example.com" - an 18 character string. If your site changes to exampletwo.com, it would have to be updated to s:21"http://exampletwo.com". If you don't update these, WordPress can't make sense of it and you'll lose your text widgets, rev sliders, etc..

The simplest way to move the database portion is by first installing a plugin to change those strings for you. [WP Migrate DB](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-migrate-db/) works great.

After you've exported the modified database, move all of your files, update wp-config.php with the new database credentials & salts, update the rewrite base in the .htaccess if needed, then import the migration database using phpMyAdmin.

At this point you should be all set. Browse the site to make sure nothing is broken. In some cases, you may need to log in and re-save your permalink structure.

Cheers!